Is there a in-depth paper published about the Cloudflare's Lavarand and their CSPRNG?
I am diving into Cloudflare's Lavarand and its Cryptographically Secure Pseudo-Random Number Generator (CSPRNG) [1]. Does anyone know of any comprehensive papers or documentation that provide an in-depth look at Lavarand's CSPRNG implementation? Interested in understanding its cryptographic principles, and design rationale. Thanks in advance.

You've already linked to the patent here. As usual, it's not a great read as that's not the purpose of a patent. You should be able to get fair idea though of how the original one worked - sensor noise.
But you'll appreciate that it's all of a bit of a marketing con on behalf of Cloudflare. It looks great and makes good copy.  Notice that the Design section of the description includes three entropy sources in addition to the lamp image. There's camera sensor noise and two other local sources which are probably the cryptographic sources from the machines' OSes. Mix them all together and off you go.
But Cloudflare doesn't really use this construct:- "Hopefully we’ll never need LavaRand. Hopefully, the primary entropy sources used by our production machines will remain secure, and LavaRand will serve little purpose beyond adding some flair to our office."
